# Firebase Cloud Messaging No valid registration ids

Tags: c#, json, .net, firebase, fcm

quisiera consultar, porque cuando quiero registrar un nuevo usuario en alguna de mis aplicaciones, firebase, por momentos totalmente aleatorios (ahora casi permanente) me tira error de "no valid registration ids" el API de FCM, por lo que no me permite registrar ningun usuario nuevo, y sin embargo, no hice ninguna modificacion en los ultimos meses como para que esto fallara, es mas, en un principio (no inicie el proyecto yo), corregi el pasaje de terminos para armar el json correspondiente y habia comenzado a funcionar correctamente, paso el sender id en el project_id como mucha gente lo explica, y el registration_id es el id que devuelve firebase para el registro, y me devuelve ese error una vez que intento enviar el json para el registro.
adjunto captura del codigo correspondiente.
intente buscar una solucion por google, pero todo lo que encuentro es maximo de octubre de 2017, nada mas nuevo, no se si sera porque no se usa tanto o porque realmente no hay mas problemas ultimamente.
el lenguaje usado para todo esto, es C# ya que este fragmento de codigo pertenece a un backend que agrupa aplicaciones para manejar las suscripciones de las notificaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estas obteniendo los tokens?

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()